# Why dont work "IN" compare wordpress in get_posts()?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have acf field "checkbox". With 3 values:

- red : Red
- green : Green
- blue : Blue

In posts I select the following values, but I can’t get records for these values.

```php
$posts = get_posts([
 'post_type'  => 'products', //my custom post type
 'meta_query' => [
  'relation' => 'AND',
  [
   'key' => 'colors',// acf field name
   'value' => ['green', 'blue'],
   'compare' => 'IN',
  ],
  [...],
 ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why IN would not work in this scenario is that the value ACF stores for a checkbox field is a serialized PHP string.

As examples storing the colors you mentioned, you would end up with values such as below saved in the meta_value database field:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:3:"red";i:1;s:5:"green";i:2;s:4:"blue";}
a:1:{i:0;s:3:"red";}
a:2:{i:0;s:3:"red";i:1;s:5:"green";}
a:1:{i:0;s:4:"blue";}
```

To query the above using IN, you would need to do something like this, where you consider the values stored.

```php
$posts = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key' => 'colors',
            'value' => ['a:1:{i:0;s:4:"blue";}', 'a:1:{i:0;s:4:"green";}'],
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ]
    ],
]);
```

In order to query these in a sane manner, you will need to treat the entire field as a string of data and perform a LIKE compare/comparison.

And to make sure you get the proper values you can used the double quotes around the string to match ie using '"red"' instead of just 'red' thinking as a string. Where the double quotes do not have any special meaning.

Both '"red"' and 'red' would work but the latter will also match reddragon with LIKE.

Your code would look something like this, and of course continue to add more and nest meta_query sections as required.

```php
$posts = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'key' => 'colors',
            'value' => '"green"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'colors',
            'value' => '"blue"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Based on the method you use, you may need to change the 'relation' for 'meta_query' appropriately.